# BoomMenu listener - starting activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using [BoomMenu](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu) in my app. I want to start another activity after clicking one of the buttons, but I get an error ("Cannot resolve constructor").

```
bmb.addBuilder(new SimpleCircleButton.Builder().normalImageRes(R.drawable.ic_add_white_48dp)
            .listener(new OnBMClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBoomButtonClick(int index) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }));
```

> Error:(98, 41) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(,Class)
>
> constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to String)
>
> constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch;  cannot be converted to Context)

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "this" directly, try YourClassName.this